# How long does it take to drive from Heathrow airport to Covent Garden?

Tags: london, tips-and-tricks, lhr

I am travelling with my family for a holiday in England. I am looking at renting an apartment in Covent Garden. What would be the drive time to and from Heathrow airport?

Comment: Have you tried to use a navigation software? Google maps might be of good help. Or if you plan to use the subway, you can calculate the travel time on the London subway page.

Comment: Be smart, take the Heathrow Express to Paddington and then hail a taxi from the cab ranks there. Arguably faster and you have a Zone 1 taxi fare rather than a Zone 5 taxi fare. (about a 50% reduction)

Comment: @GayotFow As others have pointed out, the Piccadilly line will likely be even faster (and much cheaper) here.

Comment: @Muzer indeed, I have up voted all answers and will continue to do so. Also +1 for the question!

Comment: And are you trying this on a weekday or a weekend ? Weekends may look easy but they aren't, summer and tourists are in plenty. And if some event is going on you will end up spending loads of time on the road.

Comment: @Muzer Piccadilly at the weekend once took me half again to cross London the time it took to fly across the atlantic.  Weekdays, definitely, but weekends are a gamble.  Definitely check the tube news for weekend closures and delays before hopping on.

Comment: @J... Crikey, yes, that's pretty extreme. Do check how the lines are running at https://tfl.gov.uk (you can also look up engineering work in advance on there somewhere).

Comment: @Muzer It was an extreme case, to be sure.  I think Hounslow West was on fire and the replacement bus to Central was overbooked... track was out at South Ealing for about 45min also so we spent a good part of the morning just sat between stations staring at our feet. 0_o

Comment: I wouldn't bother asking here when Rome2Rio exists. It's great for this sort of thing: https://www.rome2rio.com/s/London-Heathrow-Airport-LHR/Covent-Garden

Comment: Right now, 1h 14m.

Comment: To add to the answers suggesting "don't drive": Why are you thinking of hiring a car at all?  Do you actually have a need for a car, or did you just assume that would be the natural thing to do?  From Covent Garden, most of Central London is pretty walkable, and Tube + Bus are good too.

Comment: If you are going to use public transport, do a little research on the best way to get around, and search out the map which shows walking time between different stations - it can often be worth getting off one line, walking a bit, and getting on another.  Also don't forget busses - the view is *much* better!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is literally what Google/Bing/Apple maps is for. Any such question is too specific to the needs of the person asking it.

Comment: You're also not going to have anywhere to park your hire car once you get into town...

Comment: @DavidRicherby the map apps might give an answer to the direct question, but they won't give the better answers of "don't drive" that the user has received.

Answer (score 74):

If you're planning to rent a car and drive to Covent Garden, one word of advice: DON'T. London traffic and parking charges (not to mention the Congestion Charge) are mental and no Londoner in their right mind would drive into the centre, let alone a tourist.

If you're getting a black cab (taxi), bear in mind it could be quicker than a Google estimate, as London cabs can use dedicated bus lanes and the drivers have years of experience. The time it will take will vary hugely depending on the time of day. Anything from 30 minutes in the middle of the night to 1.5 hours (and up) in the morning rush hour.

If you're going to get the Underground, that goes direct to Covent Garden (the Picadilly line). This would probably be the quickest option and since the line starts at Heathrow, you're guaranteed seats.

Comment: I second this. Driving in London is not a good idea

Comment: @anomuse Thanks, I've added a note about the congestion charge to my answer.

Comment: I recommend downloading the free app Citymapper, which shows all of the different options for navigating London and their relative prices. It aggregates and simplifies the public transportation options of London, which is invaluable for tourists!

Comment: Yes! please do not drive if you can avoid it. Also please consider this advice when visiting any major city in the world. Your car will be an expensive anchor and when you are driving it, you will miss most of what you are driving past. You will also be a hazard to everyone else on the road.

Comment: +1 but worth noting that a black cab from Heathrow to Covent Garden is probably eye-wateringly expensive.

Comment: On the Picadilly line is it inconvenient for you and other passengers if you have a large suitcase with you?

Comment: Mildly inconvenient for other passengers; how inconvenient it is for you depends on how good you are at carrying it. But unless your apartment comes with reserved parking, carrying the suitcase is nowhere near as inconvenient as trying to park in Covent Garden.

Comment: @HankyPanky The Piccadilly Line has fewer seats/tip-up seats around the doors to act as luggage space. It can still be kind of awkward if you're not being considerate and blocking aisles for people, but it's the Piccadilly line; it certainly feels like one of the more touristy (as opposed to commuter-y) lines, and people just expect people to have luggage since it's come from Heathrow.

Comment: A thousand times this, driving in London sucks and will bankrupt you. You could hire a chauffeur-driven limo and still be better off than car hire + fuel + congestion charge + parking fees + time wasted finding parking + time wasted working out the one-way systems, roadworks and navigation...

Comment: @HankyPanky Personally at rush hour I find it very irritating to fail to squeeze onto a train because someone is taking up space with an oversized bag. After 9 am and before 5 pm I think it's fair game. But at the time of day when people are trying to get to work, the system is already dangerously overcrowded. Just my opinion ...

Comment: IMHO, even the best taxi drivers on the quietest roads couldn't make that journey in 30 mins. 45 maybe...at a push

Comment: @Calchas, stop taking the train in rush hour then, especially if you think it's dangerously overcrowded already

Comment: I normally take the tube to/from Heathrow in the morning after rush hour or in the afternoon just before and have never experienced problems bringing a large suitcase. Some years ago, bad planning meant that I had to travel through London (had been staying in Watford, flying from Heathrow) on a saturday with a suitcase, that wasn't fun.

Answer (score 21):

Google maps gives an estimate of one hour to drive from Heathrow to Covent Garden.

However - I would not recommend doing so. Driving in London is best avoided even if you're a local, and parking near Covent Garden, if you can find any, will be very expensive.

I'd recommend taking the Underground - there is a direct train from Heathrow to Covent Garden on the Picadilly line, taking around 50 minutes.

Answer (score 8):

I live not far from Covent Garden, although a little further out, still in the City of Westminster. I go to Heathrow a few times a month, usually by tube but sometimes in the car. In my experience it is about an hour's drive, mostly because of congestion in the centre, but at certain times of the day it may take much longer, so it can be hard to plan how much time you need.

I'll contradict the other answers here and say that driving in London is not that difficult compared to most European capitals, at least in my view. But I would recommend you take a taxi or an uber instead of hiring a car. Parking in Westminster for non-residents is not easy to obtain, there is a fee to enter the centre of town, and the roads are fairly confusing. At a minimum you should arrange parking in advance if you really think you need a car.

I would also echo the advice to take the Tube if it's easy for you, but I'll add a bit of balance and say if you do have a lot of luggage or elderly people or young kids in tow, central London public transport is very busy, it can get very hot and extremely crowded, people can be very unforgiving at rush hour of confused people with large bags, and you may find sitting in the back of an uber is much less stressful and more civilised. I usually pay about £40 for an uber each way. If you're not a fan of uber, it is cheaper and more comfortable to book a car in advance (a "minicab") rather than try to hail one at arrivals.

Comment: I live in the UK (not London any more) and find it esasier to drive in than Paris or other major European cities.  But that's all about familiarity.  It's still not a nice city to drive in.